# Error InvalidTestClassError in Appium test

Tags: android, automation, appium

I'm trying to learn how to automate mobile app tests in Appium.
I have a strange problem. The test throws me an error:

org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'com.example.TestMovil':

1. Method main() should not be static
2. Method main should have no parameters

The strangest thing of all is that when I wrote the test everything worked fine, it was when I restarted it days later that it started to fail.
I show you the code:

```
package com.example;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class TestMovil {
    @Test
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    try{
        testAutoMovil();
    }catch(Exception exp){
        System.out.println(exp.getCause());
        System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void testAutoMovil() throws MalformedURLException{

        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driverAndroid;
        System.out.println("Creación del driver");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi Note 8 Pro");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "heifzt9xypk7jbtc");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "10");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.xxx.xxx");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.xxx.views.activities.contexts.login.LoginActivity");

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");

        driverAndroid = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement> (url, capabilities);
        driverAndroid.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Aplicación comienza");

        MobileElement iniciarSesion = driverAndroid.findElement(By.id("com.xxx.xxx:id/activity_onboarding_sign_in_button"));
        iniciarSesion.click();
    }
}
```

Try to test a login session on Android device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests should be under `src/test` folder, therefore there is no `main` method. You should remove the main method, right click on the file and run it if you use IDE, otherwise, you need to use CLI.

The end result would look like this :

```java
package com.example;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class TestMovil {
    
    @Test
    public static void testAutoMovil() throws MalformedURLException{

        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driverAndroid;
        System.out.println("Creación del driver");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi Note 8 Pro");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "heifzt9xypk7jbtc");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "10");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.correos.prepago");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.marcanditasl.bnext.architecture.views.activities.contexts.login.LoginActivity");

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");

        driverAndroid = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement> (url, capabilities);
        driverAndroid.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Aplicación comienza");

        MobileElement iniciarSesion = driverAndroid.findElement(By.id("com.correos.prepago:id/activity_onboarding_sign_in_button"));
        iniciarSesion.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's strange, because I wrote the code looking at a tutorial and the first time I ran it, it worked without problems.